# Uninitialized value in Python?

Tags: python

What's the uninitialized value in Python, so I can compare if something is initialized, like:

```
val

if val == undefined ?
```

EDIT: added a pseudo keyword.

EDIT2: I think I didn't make it clear, but say val is already there, but nothing is assigned to it.

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to do that?  There's probably a more "pythonic" way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Since variables are just tags attached to objects, the whole question is very non-pythonic.  The idea of "uninitialized" can't exist -- this question is quite strange.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Will throw a `NameError` exception:

```
>>> val
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'val' is not defined
```

You can either catch that or use `'val' in dir()`, i.e.:

```
try:
    val
except NameError:
    print("val not set")
```

or

```
if 'val' in dir():
    print('val set')
else:
    print('val not set')
```

Comment: There could be UnboundLocalError in local scope.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian Huh? UnboundLocalError is a subclass of NameError, isn't it?

Comment: @phihag: Yes, it is. I've thought It is worth pointing out the difference between "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'val' referenced before assignment" and "NameError: global name 'val' is not defined".

Comment: You will get a ULE if val is assigned to some time later within the same function.

Comment: wrong answer. var = None is what he wants. See his duplicate question

Comment: @hasen j var = None might be what the orginal author wanted, but he or she is not the only one interested in this

Answer (score 5):

In python, variables either refer to an object, or they don't exist. If they don't exist, you will get a NameError.   Of course, one of the objects they might refer to is `None`.

```
try:
   val
except NameError:
   print "val is not set"


if val is None:
   print "val is None"
```

Comment: So can't I assume val is None?

Comment: No, val won't even exist until the first time you refer to it.  You can do val = None to 'initialize' but that's probably unpythonic.

Comment: Thanks Dana. It's just that I wanna know if it's initialized.

Answer (score 5):

A name does not exist unless a value is assigned to it. There is None, which generally represents no usable value, but it is a value in its own right.

Answer (score 4):

This question leads on to some fun diversions concerning the nature of python objects and it's garbage collector:

It's probably helpful to understand that all variables in python are really pointers, that is they are names in a namespace (implemented as a hash-table) whch point to an address in memory where the object actually resides.

Asking for the value of an uninitialized variable is the same as asking for the value of the thing a pointer points to when the pointer has not yet been created yet... it's obviously nonsense which is why the most sensible thing Python can do is throw a meaningful NameError.

Another oddity of the python language is that it's possible that an object exists long before you execute an assignment statement. Consider:

```
a = 1
```

Did you magically create an int(1) object here? Nope - it already existed. Since int(1) is an immutable singleton there are already a few hundred pointers to it:

```
>>> sys.getrefcount(a)
592
>>>
```

Fun, eh?

**EDIT:** commment by JFS (posted here to show the code)

```
>>> a = 1 + 1
>>> sys.getrefcount(a) # integers less than 256 (or so) are cached
145
>>> b = 1000 + 1000
>>> sys.getrefcount(b) 
2
>>> sys.getrefcount(2000)
3
>>> sys.getrefcount(1000+1000)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, for a variable to exist, something must have been assigned to it.  You can think of your variable name as a dictionary key that must have some value associated with it (even if that value is None).

Answer (score 1):

**Q: How do I discover if a variable is defined at a point in my code?**

**A: Read up in the source file until you see a line where that variable is defined.**

Answer (score 1):

Usually a value of `None` is used to mark something as "declared but not yet initialized; I would consider an uninitialized variable a defekt in the code

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    print val
except NameError:
    print "val wasn't set."
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to [phihag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664219/uninitialized-value-of-python/664222#664222): you can use [`dir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) to get a list of all of the variables in the current scope, so if you want to test if `var` is in the current scope without using exceptions, you can do:

```
if 'var' in dir():
    # var is in scope
```